# Notifications showing no content

Tags: notifications, iphone, ios

Whenever I get notifications, there is no content, or the content that should be there.

[image][image][image][image]

- In the News notifications and Google notifications, it only shows bold text, not any details like it should.
- In WhatsApp notifications, it shows the name of the person and the group, but for the content it just shows "(null)".
- For emails, it just shows the name of the sender, and shows "Mail message" underneath it.
- For texts from the stock messages app, it just shows the sender's name and "iMessage" underneath it instead of showing the messages content.

How do I fix this and make notifications show the content properly? I have searched everywhere, but I can't find any solutions.

I am running the latest iOS version 10.2.1 on iPhone 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by simply updating to the latest iOS version.